# hadoop_starting daemon_no file or directory error

Tags: hadoop, daemon

**usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: No such file or directory**
 I am getting this error message when I run **start-dfs.sh.**
kindly anyone give me the solution with the correct steps to follow.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to `usr/local/hadoop/sbin` look if there any file named `hadoop-daemons.sh`
   1.1 if exits then give proper permission to the file to run it .
   1.2 if no then your hadoop installation folder missing it. please reinstall then.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that whether you have set required paths:

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```